# How to export and import chrome://flags

Tags: chrome-for-android

I do **not** want to export the bookmarks and I do **not** want to export the passwords. I **only** want to export whatever is shown in `chrome://flags`.

Specifically I want to export from an Android 4.4.4 device with Chrome 62.0.3202.84 and I want to import that to an Android 5.1.1 device with Chrome 62.0.3202.84.

Manually scrolling through and comparing the whole list is not an acceptable solution.

Even better would be a way to find out which flags differ from the default value, just like Firefox does in `about:config`.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to do this manually by examining and copy/pasting the raw content where Chrome stores the flags, but **root access is needed**.

The file that stores the flags is located on:

- `/data/user/0/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Local State` (according to [Chromium's Official Documentation](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/user_data_dir.md#Android))
- `/data/data/com.android.chrome/app_chrome/Local State` (based on testing and experience, possibly for single-account user)

The file `Local State` (without extension) is in JSON format, which is actually a normal text file and can be opened with any text editor **having root access** ([Root Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.speedsoftware.rootexplorer) includes text editor, but it's not free).

Thanks to [Synetech's answer on Super User](https://superuser.com/a/489131/356789), the flags are stored under `enabled_labs_experiment` JSON array in the `browser` JSON object node.

Example (taken from the answer)

```
{
  …
  "browser": {
    "enabled_labs_experiments": [ "disable-gpu-vsync", "extension-apis", … ],
    …
  }
  …
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I only have root access on the 5.1.1 device but not the 4.4.4 one. I tried both options given at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device/17876731#17876731 but the first one doesn't work because of https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36976703 and the second one doesn't because for some reason zlib complains about invalid headers. I'll give you a +1 because your answer is still useful for future reference and possibly other users, but I can't mark it as accepted.